# How to prevent creating ".mdmp" and ".hdmp" files when unhadled exceptions happens

Tags: windows, visual-studio, console-application, dump, windows-error-reporting

Our C# console application works fine. this application internally runs some C++ dlls. Occasionally, we encounter to C5 Error (unknown C++ error of underlying dlls) or unhadled C# Exceptions which both terminates the application. (I saw it in Windows Event Log).

The problem is not the error but the dump file that is generated in Windows' Temp folder. It fills our disk (virtual disk with very low space), and result in failing other running applications.
These are 2 files with ".mdmp" and ".hdmp" extensions. they occupies about 500MB. I read on the internet that these are related to "Windows Error Reporting", but I checked in our Windows setting (server manager-->Local Server) and it is off.

I also changed a build setting for our C# console application called: "Internal compiler error reporting" to "send"; Hopping that it send the dump file to somewhere that it intended to and do not save it for latter, but temp files still are generated on disk. I think I should change it to "none".

please help me if there is a way to stop creating these temp files.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to exclude your exe from error reporting. See "ExcludedApplications" here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638.aspx.

I don't have enough points to reply inline to the previous answer. So replying here. The settings mentioned in the previous answer is for system crashes, aka Blue screens. Those settings don't affect user-mode application crashes.

Comment: As I told: in our Windows Server 2012 under "Server Manager"-->"Local Server" there is a setting for  "Windows Error Reporting" that is off. Do you still say "Windows Error Reporting" still working?

Answer (score 0):

In old Environment like Windows Server 2003, to disable the .HDMP files on a machine, just right click on "My Computer" and click 'Properties', go to tab 'Advanced' and click 'Error Reporting', there you could disable it.

Comment: under that Windows` setting for the name of the Dump file is written:"%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP". even with this setting you say it is related to create   .HDMP created in Window`s Temp folder?

Comment: They are memory dump file, just ignore it. Just find a document shared different ways to disable the windows Error reporting even if in windows 7: http://techrena.net/disable-windows-7-error-reporting/. You would try to check it in your side. My understanding is that it would be related to the Windows/windows server, it would be not the MSbuild issue.  So I just provide some suggestions for you. I also will help you add other tags and move the MSbuild tag.